# Taking the sum and average of the keyboard inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics

I have an assignment as follows:

> Write a program where you can enter from the keyboard up to 10
>   integers. If the number entered is equal to -99, stop reading numbers
>   from the keyboard and compute the average and sum of all values
>   (excluding -99). Print the average on the screen. Make sure you
>   consider all the cases: less than 10 or exactly 10 numbers can be
>   entered. After the numbers have been entered you need to make sure
>   that the average is computed then.

I came up with the program below. Do you think my program is fine? What could be alternative solutions?

```
s = 0
for i in range(1, 11):
    a=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if a==-99:
        s = s+a
        print("The sum of the numbers that you've entered excluding -99:",s-a) # minus a because we want to exclude -99
        print("The average of the numbers that you've entered excluding -99:",(s-a)/(i-1)) # minus a because we want to exclude -99. i-1 in denominator because we excluded -99 from the sum.
        break
    else:
        s = s+a
        print("The sum of the number(s) that you've entered:",s)
        print("The average of the number(s) that you've entered:",s/i)
        continue
input("Press enter to close")
```

Comment: have you read the assignment? `excluding -99`. Also you are displaying results after every input.

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted if you think it answers your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

The application should do 2 things.

> 1. Collect up to 10 different integers, or until the entered value is -99
> 2. Sum and Average the values

```
# so lets start by creating a list and fill it with all the numbers we need
numbers = list() 
for i in range(0, 10): 
    inputNr = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if(inputNr == -99):
        break;

    numbers.append(inputNr)

#Then we take all of the numbers and calculate the sum and avg on them
sum = 0
for j, val in enumerate(numbers):
    sum += val

print("The total sum is: " + str(sum))
print("The avg is: " + str(sum / len(numbers)))
```

A few pointers about your code:

- Use a whitespace (a single space) between variable declaration and assignment. Where you did `a=1` you want to do `a = 1`
- You usually iterate an array (or in Pythons case a list) from `0 to N`, and not `1 to N`
- Create variables which you can reuse. As you can see in my example I create a `inputNr` variable which holds the input. I later reuse this to check if it's `-99` and I reuse it by adding it to my list
- variable names, function names, and everything else should have a descriptive and concise name. Where you named your input variable to `a` I named mine to `inputNr`. This means that when we later reuse this variable in the code it will be clear to us what it is and what it holds.

Comment: I would remove the unused `j` and `enumerate`, leaving just `for val in numbers: sum += val`. Or, better, use `sum()` for the whole thing.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Good point! I'm still new to Python...

Answer (score 2):

A few things that spring to mind:

> 1. Keeping a running total is a good idea but take care to catch the `-99` case - there's no need to add it to the total at all.
> 2. I like how you're using range to count the inputs.  This, plus the first point means you don't have to store the actual inputs anywhere.
> 3. My personal oppinion:  Your division is fine but would not work in python 2.x.  I prefer explicit integer/float division to avoid this ambiguity.  You could start with `s` as a float, `s = 0.` or force float division `s * 1. / i` .
> 4. You could use string substitution to format your output in a nice way. [See here in the docs.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)
> 5. `break` is required but `continue` is not.  You should read `continue` as "continue to next loop iteration, do not execute any more code until you get there".  As there is no more code in the loop after `continue`, it is not needed.

Here's my version:

```
s = 0  # Ok in python 3, for 2.x explicitly use a float s = 0.
for i in range(1, 11):
    n = int(input())  # Careful to only enter numbers here
    if n == -99:
        i -= 1
        break
    s += n
i = i if i else 1  # Avoids ZeroDivisionError
print 'The sum was: {}\nThe average was: {}'.format(s, s/i)
```

Comment: Given the `python3` tag, points 3 and 4 are not necessary here. Still they're good reference for `python2` users.

Comment: thanks MichaelUrman, I didn't notice that tag. I'll edit the post to take it into account

Comment: your code doesn't properly return the average

Comment: @Malachi - Apologies, the -99 case should have subtracted 1 from i.  Fixed now.